# Android Huawei image segmentation not working on release build

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

I'm using Huawei image segmentation for background removal from images. This code work perfectly fine on **debug build** but it does not work on a **release build**. I don't understand what could be the case.

**Code:**

```
  private fun imageSegmentation(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
            if (bitmap == null) {
                dialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Something went wrong. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                return
            }
    
            val setting =
                MLImageSegmentationSetting.Factory()
                    .setAnalyzerType(MLImageSegmentationSetting.BODY_SEG)
                    .setExact(true)
                    .create()
            val analyzer = MLAnalyzerFactory.getInstance().getImageSegmentationAnalyzer(setting)
            val mlFrame = MLFrame.Creator().setBitmap(bitmap).create()
            val task = analyzer?.asyncAnalyseFrame(mlFrame)
            task?.addOnSuccessListener { mlImageSegmentationResults ->
                if (mlImageSegmentationResults != null) {
                    removalFlag = true
                    removalBitmap = mlImageSegmentationResults.foreground
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No human body is detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }?.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No human body is detected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
```

**Dependencies:**

```
 implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-segmentation:2.2.0.300'
 implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-body-model:2.2.0.300'
```

**Note**: According to my understanding the `task?.addOnSuccessListener` is called but `mlImageSegmentationResults` return's **null**.

Comment: Do you have Proguard enabled in release build? Stuff like this is usually Proguards "fault".

Comment: hi@ahmad bajwa, could you mind share your test device model, the stack trace or any logs of the debug and release build you're having, so we can help you properly?

Comment: Yeah, I have enabled the proguard.

Comment: @shirley, I don't think stack trace will help if mlImageSegmentationResults is null.

Comment: @PrimožIvančič Yesh the issue was Proguard. but the google play console gives us a warning if we set to disable.

Comment: @ahmad bajwa, it will be great If you can provide more detailed log information for us to check

Comment: @shirley thanks for your help – Primož Ivančič was right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stuff like this usually happens when you have ProGuard enabled but not correctly configured. Make sure to add appropriate rules to `proguard-rules.pro` file to prevent it from obfuscating relevant classes.

Information about this is usually provided by the library developers. After a quick search I came up with [this example](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-guides/config-obfuscation-scripts-0000001050038100). Sources seem to be documented well enough, so that it should not be a problem to find the correct settings.

Keep in mind that you probably need to add rules for more than one library.